# Is matroid realizability computable?

Tags: co.combinatorics, matroid-theory

I attended a talk which generalized matroid realizability over a field to matroid realizability over division rings, and showed that the question of realizability is undecidable. However, they used a word problem arising from the division ring.

Is it known whether the question of "Is a matroid M realizable over any field F" is computable?

It seems to me that it shouldn't be, because they you would have a prover of all theorems akin to the Pappus theorem, but that's just my intuition.

Comment: Here's a somewhat related paper where Sturmfels shows that realizability over $\mathbb{Q}$ of matroids is equivalent to Hilbert's 10th problem over $\mathbb{Q}$: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183553968

Comment: Of course I understand you're asking about realizability over any field. Possibly Mnev's Universality Theorem is relevant here.

Comment: Yes, it is computable. I think Oxley's book has a proof (but regardless of whether or not it does, it is true).

Comment: Found it: theorem 6.8.9.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Contra my suspicions, the Internet is telling me that Vámos proved in "A necessary and sufficient condition for a matroid to be linear" (citation below) that it is decidable if a matroid is representable over a field. See quote on pg. 3 of [Solving Rota’s Conjecture](https://homepages.ecs.vuw.ac.nz/~whittle/pubs/solving-rotas-conjecture.pdf) which says "The first exception is the algorithmic problem of determining when a given matroid is representable over an unspecified field, which was proved to be decidable by Vámos [28]."

*Vamos, P.*, A necessary and sufficient condition for a matroid to be linear, Möbius Algebras, Conf. Proc. Waterloo 1971, 162-169 (1975). [ZBL0374.05017](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0374.05017).

**EDIT**:

Since the Vámos reference seems hard to track down, let me quote from the MathReviews [MR0349447] by J. E. Graver, which gives more details about the result:

> The author gives a necessary and sufficient condition for a matroid to be $f$-linear, i.e., representable over some field. Let $E$ be a set and $\scr{E}$ a collection of subsets of $E$ satisfying the conditions for the independent sets of a matroid on $E$. We denote this matroid by the pair $(E,\mathscr{E})$. Fix $B\in \mathscr{E}$, a basis for the matroid. For each $x\in E$ define $S(a)$ as follows: $S(a)=\varnothing$ if $\{a\}\notin \mathscr{E}$; $S(a)=\{a\}$ if $a\in B$; otherwise $S(a)$ is the unique subset of $B$ such that $S(a)∪\{a\}$ is a circuit. Let $\Gamma=\{(a,b):a\in E,b\in S(a)\}$, and consider $R=Z[X_{\gamma}]$, the ring of polynomials over the integers in variables $\{X_\gamma: \gamma \in \Gamma\}$. A finite subset $A \subseteq E$ is said to be regular if $|A|=|\bigcup_{a \in A}S(a)|$. For each regular set $A$ a polynomial in $R$ is constructed as follows: Let $r_{(a,b)}=X_{(a,b)}$ if $a \in A$ and $b \in S(a)$, and $r_{(a,b)}=0$ if $a\in A$ and $b\in A−S(a)$. Ordering the elements of $A$, constructing the $|A|\times |A|$ matrix $[r_{(a,b)}]$ and taking the determinant yield a polynomial $P(A)$, unique up to sign. However, the ideal $I$ generated by $\{P(A):\textrm{$A$ is regular}, A\notin \mathscr{E}\}$ and the multiplicatively closed set $T$ generated by $\{P(A):\textrm{$A$ is regular}, A\in \mathscr{E}\}$ are uniquely determined. We may now state the main result. Theorem: The matroid $E, \mathscr{E}$ is $f$-linear if and only if $T\cap I=\varnothing$.

Note that in the review there is a confusing typo where it describes $T$ as generated by $\{P(A):\textrm{$A$ is regular}, A\notin \mathscr{E}\}$ rather than $\{P(A):\textrm{$A$ is regular}, A\in \mathscr{E}\}$. Note also, as pointed out in the comments by Geva Yashfe, that this result appears as Theorem 6.8.9 in the 2nd edition of Oxley's Matroid Theory text, which is probably a more accessible source. To deduce decidability from this algebraic crieterion, Oxley appeals to Gröbner basis theory.

Comment: Nice find! I'm currently trying to figure out a way to access that paper.

Comment: However, that problem is still different from my problem, I think? Specifying a field for the algorithm is different from allowing ANY field.

Comment: @bottledcaps: I'm pretty sure it's the same problem. You're asking: is there any F such that my M is realizable, right?

Comment: I agree that this reference (what looks like conference proceedings) is pretty hard to track down though.

Comment: @SamHopkins There is a mistake in the statement above, and possibly in the review. It should be $T = \{P(A) : A\text{ is regular, } A \in \mathscr{E}\}$. (Instead of $\notin$.)
The point is: you want to invert the determinants which should be invertible, demand the determinants of dependent subsets' column-sets vanish, and check whether the resulting quotient is not the zero ring (in which case there is a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ containing $I$ in a localization inverting $T$, and this gives a representation in the field $\mathbb{Z}[x_{i,j}]/\mathfrak{m}$).

Comment: @GevaYashfe: Thanks, that makes sense. The typo is indeed in the review. I will correct it above though. I see that as you mentioned this is also in (the 2nd edition) of Oxley's Matroid Theory book, Theorem 6.8.9, with what looks to be the same proof.

Answer (score 10):

Sam Hopkins has answered what I think is your stated question.  But in the comments, it seems that you're also interested in the following question: Given a matroid $M$ and field $F$, is it decidable whether $M$ is $F$-representable?

In Oxley's book *Matroid Theory* (2nd edition), he discusses this problem on pages 226–227. If $F$ is a finite field then decidability is trivial since the rank of the matroid tells you the dimension of the vector space to try.  For infinite fields the situation is more subtle; for starters, one has to address the question of what it means to be "given" $F$.  Gröbner basis algorithms may solve the problem if $F$ is algebraically closed.  On the other hand, Sturmfels ([On the decidability of Diophantine problems in combinatorial geometry](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.308.2138&rep=rep1&type=pdf), *Bull. Amer. Math. Soc.* **17** (1987), 121–124) has shown that for $F=\mathbb{Q}$, the question is equivalent to Hilbert's 10th problem for $\mathbb{Q}$, which remains an open problem at the time of this writing.

Comment: For $\mathbb{R}$ it is apparently also decidable as mentioned here as a result of the real nullstellsatz: https://mathoverflow.net/a/48185/25028. I wonder if there is any field $F$ (however artificial) for which realizability is known to be undecidable?

Comment: Ahh, I realize I am thinking of the problem: fix a field $F$; is there an algorithm which decides if a matroid $M$ is $F$-representable? As you say, if $F$ is part of the input you have to be careful about what it means to be given $F$. But I think the field-by-field algorithm question is totally clear.

Comment: @SamHopkins This is equivalent to solvability of polynomial equations in $F$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$.
There are fields for which there are strong undecidability results (for instance, equations with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[t_1,t_2]$ cannot be solved algorithmically over $\mathbb{C}(t_1,t_2)$), but I'm not aware of any $F$ (unless very artificial) for which it is known.

Answer (score 3):

A matroid being representable is equivalent to a certain locally closed subscheme of the Grassmannian, defined by the non-vanishing of the Plücker coordinates corresponding to bases and the vanishing of the Plücker coordinates coordinates corresponding to non-bases, being nonempty. This can be done (using Gröbner basis algorithms) in a few different ways.

In the paper [Singular matroid realization spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.11915), Dan Corey and Dante Luber have written code in OSCAR which does this, apparently quite efficiently. Remarkably, they were able to determine exactly which matroids of rank 3 on 11 elements are realizable over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: The link to the GitHub repository for their code that they post in the paper ([being this one](https://github.com/dcorey2814/matroidRealizationSpaces)) is broken...

Comment: This answers (and IMHO is the “right” answer to) the question of algorithmically deciding whether a matroid, or indeed any configuration of linear subspaces, is representable *over a field of given characteristic*. I think one needs to add a little explanation as to why it's decidable whether a system of algebraic equations (with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$) has a solution *over any field* (which is true, but the reason momentarily escapes me).

Comment: There are Gröbner basis algorithms that work over $\mathbb{Z}$, e.g., can decide is some polynomials generate the unit ideal over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Being decidable is a very weak property - one can also ask about the exact complexity class of this problem.  In fact, post-Mnёv theorem this is extremely well understood.  I recommend Matoušek's [survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2636) which explains why over $\Bbb R$ the problem is $\exists\Bbb R$-complete.  Here "realizability" in the special case of rank $3$ oriented matroids becomes a question of "stretchability" of *pseudoline arrangements*.